# How to edit single record shown in separate datagridview?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview in form1, when i double click a record on that datagridview it takes the number writen in ID column of that row and sends it to form2 as a string. and in form2 i have 2 datagridview one shows customer's basic info table and second one shows detailed info of the customer from the database table, so i have 2 diffrent info table for customers and i show them both in form2 but for only single record which was doubleclicked before. Now in this form2 i want to be able to edit the info infront of me. I get the succesfull message but nothing changes in database. here is my code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick ( object sender , DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e )
            {
            var frm2 = new Form2 ( dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells [ 0 ].Value.ToString () );
            frm2.Show ();
            }
```

and in form2 i have this:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
    public Form2 (string s)
        {
        InitializeComponent ();
        MessageBox.Show (s);
            SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection ( @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;" );
            DataTable customercontacttablo = new DataTable ();
            SqlDataAdapter customercontactadaptor = new SqlDataAdapter ( "select * from Customer_Contact where Cus_ID = '"+s+"'" , baglanti );
            customercontactadaptor.Fill ( customercontacttablo );
            customer_ContactDataGridView.DataSource = customercontacttablo;
            DataTable customertablo = new DataTable ();
            SqlDataAdapter customeradaptor = new SqlDataAdapter ( " SELECT * from Customer where ID = '"+s+"'",baglanti);
            customeradaptor.Fill ( customertablo );
            customerDataGridView.DataSource = customertablo;
        }

    private void Form2_Load ( object sender , EventArgs e )
        {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database1DataSet1.Customer' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.customerTableAdapter.Fill ( this.database1DataSet1.Customer );
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database1DataSet1.Customer_Contact' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.customer_ContactTableAdapter.Fill ( this.database1DataSet1.Customer_Contact );

        }

    private void button1_Click ( object sender , EventArgs e )
        {
            this.Validate ();
            this.customerBindingSource.EndEdit ();
            this.customer_ContactBindingSource.EndEdit ();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll ( this.database1DataSet1 );
            MessageBox.Show ( "Edit succesfull." );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to parameterize your queries before you get a visit from little bobby tables. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: As for the problem at hand I don't see where you are passing the new values anywhere but you haven't shared all your code. It looks like you are passing the DataSet to the Update method. Where do the new values get passed in?